# $location.path() is fixed before state resolve

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router

My page consist a static navbar and ui-view below it. I am checking in navbar the current $location:

```
<div ng-show="checkPath('/browse')"> foo </div>
```

And in navbar controller:

```
$scope.checkPath = function(path) {
    if ($location.path() === path) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

However, I am using the resolve in my $stateProvider (for url: '/browse') and when I redirect to '/browse', navbar behaves like it is already in '/browse', even when the promise is rejected (so I get some flickering). In other words, when I have to wait 1 second for the promise to be rejected, during the waiting - the 'ng-show' part is displayed, and after this 1 second - it is gone.

```
.state('browse', {
    [...]
    resolve: {
        foo: ['MyResource', function (MyResource) {
                MyResource.checkIfICanRouteToBrowse();
              }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.checkPath = function(path) {
    if ($location.path() === path) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

This will be executed only once when initial controller is executed, any change in state does not change this, one way to achieve this

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    $scope.checkPath = toState.name === 'browse'
                });
```

Another option that may work,

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    $scope.checkPath = function(path) {
    if ($location.path() === path) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
                });
```

Comment: That worked great! In the meantime, I have found another solution - just to use $state.current.name instead of $location.path()